# Managed Disks - Delete source blob?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-managed-disk

I have a Windows VM that was built on the old "classic" model which I would like to change to the ARM model. I have used the automated methods however this doesn't give me the control I desire (the names of all the components are messy).

- I have deleted the original VM leaving only the VHD in the storage account.
- I have created a Managed Disk (MD) using the VHD as the source blob.
- I have created a VM using the MD

When I look at the MD in the Azure portal, it still references the "Source Blob" but i'm not sure if this means the MD is still reliant on the blob and storage account or if it's just legacy/reference info.

What I need to know is, can I delete the original storage account containing the VHD now that I have a MD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a backup first and then delete the backup

Comment: so does this mean you can? @ChristophBerthoud

Comment: Yep. The managed disk still reports the Source Blob property but there is no actually connection/relationship.